# How to delete a file using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have a button in my program that will delete a certain file when clicked, such as example.txt. The code I have to delete it is:

```
File.Delete("example.txt")
```

But the file is still there. I have done some research and most people say that it should work. Why is this not working? Or is this code wrong?

Comment: Try doing a File.Exists("example.txt") to ensure you are not looking in a different folder.

Comment: You have to the whole path of your file. It has some defaults of you dont

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? [File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) should work.

Comment: I figured it out, it was inside a for each statement. for some reason it didnt like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This one doesn't require so much mystery :)

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(ADDRESS_OF_FILE_AS_STRING)
```

Answer (score 8):

Deleting a file is quite simple - but dangerous! So be very careful when you're trying out this code. Make sure the file you're going to delete is not needed - you won't be able to restore it from the recycle bin!

To delete a file from your computer, you use the Delete method of System.IO. Here's some new code for you to try:

```
Dim FileToDelete As String

FileToDelete = "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\testDelete.txt"

If System.IO.File.Exists( FileToDelete ) = True Then

System.IO.File.Delete( FileToDelete )
MsgBox("File Deleted")

End If
```

Comment: `File.Exists` is not necessary. See [help on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx). `If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.`

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.IO.File.Delete( "filepath" )
```

Comment: Please do not just throw a piece of code as answer in the ring. Explain why it helps answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this it works for me

```
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("the file",
       FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs,
       FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin,
       FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
```

put this where you want to execute it.
This sends to recycle bin.